# jQuery multi-dimensional array name selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors, multidimensional-array

Hi i'm trying to select a form input by name, however my form is setup to post into a multi-dimensional array

I'm trying to use

> $('input[name=address[permanent][street]]')

to select the element but get the following response

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=address[permanent][street]]

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Could you provide the <form> please? In a jsfiddle perhaps. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use `$('input[name="address[permanent][street]"]')` or `$('input[name="'+ index +'"]')` in your loop

Comment: Sorry I should have said I'm running this through a loop and set up like $('input[name='+ index +']') which can generates $('input[name=address[permanent][street]]') or $('input[name=forenames')

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var strAddress=address[permanent][street];
$('input[name='+strAddress+']')
```

**updated**

```
$('input[name="address[permanent][street]"]')
```

if your name of input is `address[permanent][street]`

Comment: Sorry I should have said I'm running this through a loop and set up like $('input[name='+ index +']') which can generates $('input[name=address[permanent][street]]') or $('input[name=forenames')

Comment: i am not getting you... you are saying in your loop the `index=address[permanent][street]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector: `'[name^="address"]'`